# what is a development certificate in iOS Provisioning portal?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, certificate, ios5

Can anyone please explain me the use of development certificates and how I can create a new development certificate? Also what is WWDR intermediate certificate? I found a section called certificates in iOS Provisioning portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A development certificate allows you to test on device when you have a valid provisioning file. The WWDR certificate is an intermediate certificate that validates that the other certificates come from apple.

As for *how to create* a development certificate, there are handy instructions right in the iOS portal. In a  nutshell, you'll need to download and install the WWDR certificate, and use Keychain Access's Certificate Assistant to generate a Certificate Request (Open Keychain Access, then under **Keychain Access** in the menu bar go to Certificate Assistant, and then Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority... etc) and use that to generate a certSigningRequest file (make sure you click 'save to disk' and 'specify key pairs'), upload that to the iOS provisioning portal which when approved by the team leader will give you a certificate that you download and install into keychain, and then you can install provisioning profiles that match that certificate.

Comment: I'll update my answer because they've changed the how-to a bit since I last used it.

Comment: by the way what the WWDR literally means?